# Shiny application: Jquery accordion not applying to all generated pages

Tags: jquery, r, shiny

I'm having an issue with the way my Shiny app's pages are including the jQuery I'm passing through the tags$head() function to create and format accordion elements.

**Background/Dependencies**: I'm using the shiny.router package to allow for simple routing between the pages of the app, shinyjs to include javascript (keeping this minimal though as I would like this to be fairly maintainable by someone with R experience and limited web dev knowledge), and jquery's library where helpful (icons, accordions, etc.).

**Structure**: I have a server.R file with my router logic (ex. buttons linking to other pages), ui.R with my page creation code, and global.R where I run the app. I keep my javascript files in my www folder and have jquery downloaded there as well.

The pages I am having an issue with are generated through an R function, story_page(title, description, mediafile, name)

```html
story_page<-function(title, description, mediafile, name){
  useShinyjs()
  mypage<-fluidPage(
    tagList(
      tags$head(tags$script(src="jquery-ui.min.js"),
        tags$link(rel="stylesheet", href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"),
        tags$script(HTML( '$( function() {
         $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
           collapsible: true, heightStyle: "content", icons:{"header": "ui-icon-carat-1-s", "activeHeader": "ui-icon-caret-1-n"}
         });
       } );')),),
      includeCSS("www/mytheme.css"),
      div(class="page-text-container white-background",
          div(class="grid-container",
              
              div(class="grid-element grid-header",
                  div(
                    class="page-description text-dark text",
                    div(
                      class="page-description-title",
                      title
                    ),
                    div(
                      class="file-path",
                      h6(tags$a("All Stories>",  href=route_link("all_stories")), tags$a("Futures", href=route_link("all_stories/futures")),
                         br())
                    ),
                  ),
              ),
              
              div(class="grid-element grid-video-container",
                  
                  div(class="story-page-video-container-title text","The Story"),
                  tags$video(class= "story-page-video", type = "video/mp4", src = paste0(mediafile, ".mp4", sep=""), controls=NA)
              ),
              
              div(class="grid-element grid-numbers-container",
                  div(class="grid-display story-page-numbers-column",
                         div(class="story-page-numbers-container",
                             div(class="story-page-numbers-container-title text",
                                 "The Numbers"),
                             div(class="figures",
                                 
                                 id=paste0("all-figures-container-", name, sep="")),
                         ),
                  )
              ),
              
              
              div(class="grid-element grid-learn-more text",
                  
                  div(class="story-page-related-publications-container right-border-only text dark-text",
                         div(class="story-page-related-publications-container-title",
                             "Learn more"),
                         div(class="story-page-related-publications-text text-dark",
                             "Want to learn more? Click on the links below to explore related BPDA publications, dashboards, tools, and more!",
                             tags$ul(id=paste0("links-list-container-", name, sep=""),
                                     # these will be filled in by logic explained in the server.R file (getLinks) which uses functions in the functions.R file.
                             ),
                          
                          div(id="accordion-container", class="text",
                              div(id="accordion",
                                  h3("Section 1"),
                                  div("Text text text", class="text-dark"),
                                  h3("Section 2"),
                                  div("Text text text", class="text-dark"),
                                  h3("Section 3"),
                                  div("Text text text", class="text-dark"),
                              ),
                          ),
                          
                       
                         ),
                  ),
              
              ),            
          )
      ),
    )
  )
}
```

I call this function in the ui.R file and save the created page to a variable. I do this a couple of times to create four or five unique story pages following the same format. An example call might be:

```
my_name<-story_page("My name story", my_name_description, my_name_mediafile, my_name)
```

At the end of the ui.R file, in accordance with the shiny.router package guidelines, I join all of the pages I've created and stored in variables:

```html
fluidPage(
 # theme = custom_theme,
  tags$head(tags$script(src="jquery-ui.min.js"),
        tags$link(rel="stylesheet", href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"),
        tags$script(HTML( '$( function() {
         $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
           collapsible: true, heightStyle: "content", icons:{"header": "ui-icon-carat-1-s", "activeHeader": "ui-icon-caret-1-n"}
         });
       } );')),),
  
  tags$nav(
    class="navbar navbar-expand-sm",
    # Brand
    tags$a(class="navbar-brand", href=route_link("/"), "LOGO"),

    # Toggler button

    # includeHTML(path="navbarbutton.html"),
    HTML("<button class=navbar-toggler type=button data-toggle=collapse data-target=#collapsibleNavbar>
         <img id=navbar-image src=navbar-icon.png>
           </button>"),
    # Navbar links
    div(class="collapse navbar-collapse", id="collapsibleNavbar",
        tags$ul(
          class="nav navbar-nav",
          tags$li(class="nav-item",
            a(class="nav-link", "Home", href=route_link("/"))
          ),
          tags$li(class="nav-item",
            a(class="nav-link","All Stories", href=route_link("all_stories"))
          ),
          tags$li(class="nav-item",
            a(class="nav-link","About Helen", href=route_link("about_helen"))
          ),
          tags$li(class="nav-item",
            a(class="nav-link","About The Project", href=route_link("about_the_project"))
          )
        ))
  ),
             router_ui(
               route("/", root_page),
               route("all_stories", all_stories),
               route("about_heloiza", about_helen),
               route("about_the_project", about_the_project),
               route("all_stories/futures", futures),
               route("all_stories/futures/cleo", cleo),
               route("all_stories/futures/edith", edith),
               route("all_stories/futures/ben", ben),
               route("all_stories/futures/april", april),
               route("404", error_page),
             )
)
```

The jquery applies correctly to the accordion div only for the first page generated through the function (cleo's page), but doesn't apply to the others.
I've included screenshots of the correctly displayed accordion and an incorrectly displayed accordion.

[image: correctly displayed accordion: when inspecting the code through chrome the div shows all the proper jquery ui classes]
[image: incorrectly displayed accordion: when inspecting the code the div just has the information visible on my R file, so just the accordion id and h3s]

Based on the compiled html code I can see through 'inspect', it seems like the pages with incorrectly displayed accordions are not applying jquery. The correct page shows the different accordion/header/panel etc. related classes while the incorrectly displayed pages show "accordion" as their id but none of these classes. Please note that the jquery functions perfectly fine on the first generated page.

As you can see in the last code excerpt, I added the accordion script in the overall fluid page header to see if that might solve the issue but it does not. Is this issue related to the non-uniqueness of the 'accordion' id when multiple pages are generated? My initial thought is this shouldn't be an issue, as long as the same logics and formatting are OK to apply to each page's accordion element.

I think the issue could lie somewhere in the way the shiny.router's wrapper loads the documents, however I'm afraid I'm too much of a beginner to make sense of the source code well enough to see how it generates them. The documentation for the package can be found [here](https://appsilon.github.io/shiny.router/index.html). Might you have any idea why this isn't working and how would you recommend altering my code or structure to fix this issue? Thank you so much for your help I appreciate it!